# Limit of additive functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How does one go about proving that if the limit of an additive function exists at x=0(say L),then it exists at every point c belonging to the set of real numbers.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Since $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=L$, you know that if $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $0$, then $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $L$. Let $c$ be any real number, and let $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be any sequence converging to $c$. Then $\langle x_n-c:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $0$, so $\langle f(x_n-c):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $L$. Now use the additivity of $f$ to conclude ... what?

Comment: ..To conclude that,since f(x)-f(x-c)=f(c) and since the limit on the left exists,hence the limit on the right must exist.Thank's a lot !

Comment: @Raghav: You’re welcome.